# How do I escape curly braces in Angular

Tags: angular

I have this in my HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://kart.1881.no/?direction={59.83006424|6.25588723|START}{{{latitude}}|{{longitude}}|M%C3%85L}"></iframe>
```

Notice
    `{{{latitude}}` - Here I want to escape the first {

I tried to put `\{` but it not work as well.

The error is `Missing expected : at the end of the expression`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable template binding in for part of template in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36821734/how-do-i-disable-template-binding-in-for-part-of-template-in-angular2)

Comment: Don't use the AngularJS tag  for questions about Angular 2 please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view

```
<iframe [src]="'https://kart.1881.no/?direction={59.83006424|6.25588723|START}{' + latitude + '|' + longitude + '|M%C3%85L}' | safe"></iframe>
```

And the next pipe should help you

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
    transform(url) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
}
```

You can override interpolation like

```
template: `
    <iframe src="https://kart.1881.no/?direction={59.83006424|6.25588723|START}{[[latitude]]|[[longitude]]|M%C3%85L}"></iframe>
  `,
interpolation: ['[[', ']]']
```

but anyway you have to sanitize `url` that will work only with property(not interpolation) binding

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/1ORblwKg3HB59uXOKQ0X?p=preview)**

Answer (score 4):

Simply try

```
{{'{' + latitude + '}'}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try with `%7B` for `{` and `%7D` for `}`. Those are just the URI-encoded forms, which Angular shouldn't try to parse.

Comment: Does not work Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `+` operator to concatenate the required `SRC`

`[src]="...{' + {{latitude}}+ '}...'"`

*(Update: added brackets to `src`)*

Comment: You have to change `src` to `[src]` to do that, too

Comment: don't use `[ ]`

Comment: Partyly correct. But it would give the same error as  
Does not work Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

Comment: @AngJobs, please explain why. Because if you use a string in an html property, I'm pretty sure you have to use `[ ]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the html entity `&#x007B;`

```
<iframe src="https://kart.1881.no/?direction={59.83006424|6.25588723|START}&#x007B;{{latitude}}|{{longitude}}|M%C3%85L}"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it